# How to get the row height in Excel?

Tags: excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

Is there any way to get row height of excel row in openxml?
In my case, i use openxml 2.0 to generate excel table from .net datatable. For each datatable row, i define new row in excel by

```
  row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex };
```

after that i append cell to row

```
 row.InsertBefore(newCell, refCell);
```

when finish generate excel table i want to get each row height to increase its. But it always null when use

```
    Row row = ExcelHelper.GetRow(sheetData, Convert.ToUInt32(13));
    DoubleValue a = row.Height;
```

Help me please! Thank!

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft Excel Open XML Format rows only have the `height` attribute when `customHeight` attribute is set to true in XML, otherwise the row height is just the `DefaultRowHeight`.

What you should do is first check if `row.CustomHeight != null && row.CustomHeight.Value == true` and then you know it has a custom height and the `Height` property won't be null.

In the other case you can get the default row height in the [`SheetFormatProperties.DefaultRowHeight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.sheetformatproperties.defaultrowheight?view=openxml-2.8.1).

So to set the height of a row to your custom value, you need to change its `CustomHeight` property to true, and `Height` property to your custom row height.

Comment: Thank Alexander Derck, i have cell with text value. After insert cell (with value) to cell, how could i get rowheight of row? Because after add cell to row, openxml will automatically set rowheight base on number of character in cell?

Comment: @TruongPham Still the same. Defaultrowheight unless you set a custom row height for the row. Cells don't get higher because the content doesn't fit